# How to flip a react component when i click on button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, css-animations, flipview

> ```
> I want to flip a login component along with translation when i will click on a button.I used css transition and transform property and it is flipping but the problem is here that when it flips once again it is regaining its position .I want to flip once but it is flipping twice but the position i want to gain is correct.How can i flip over with translation when i will click on button.? This is login component and i added css also with it. Anyone can help me i will appreciate the support.Thanks
> ```

i want to flip it once . Below is my code

> 

> eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
> import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
> import {Outlet, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
> import {toAbsoluteUrl} from '../../../_metronic/helpers'
> import "./authLayout.css"
> import data from "./ar.json"
> import { useLang,setLanguage } from './../../../_metronic/i18n/Metronici18n';
>
> type FlexDirection = 'ltr' | 'rtl';
>
> const directionMap: { [key: string]: FlexDirection } = {
> left: 'ltr',
> right: 'rtl'
> };
>
> const AuthLayout = () => {
> const lang = useLang()
> const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);
> const [animateLeft, setAnimateLeft] = useState(false);
> const [direction, setDirection] = useState("left")
> const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en');
> const languageTranslations = {
> en: {
> username: 'username',
> password: 'password',
> signin : "Sign In",
> continue:"CONTINUE"
> },
> ar: {
> username: 'اسم االمستخدم',
> password: 'كلمه السر',
> signin :"تسجيل الدخول",
> continue:"استمر"
> },
> };
> const text = languageTranslations[language];
>
> useEffect(() => {
> const root = document.getElementById('root')
> if (root) {
> root.style.height = '100%'
> }
> return () => {
> if (root) {
> root.style.height = 'auto'
> }
> }
> [])
>
> const handleArabicDirection = () => {
> setAnimate(animate === true)
> if(direction === "left")
> {
> setAnimateLeft(animateLeft === false)
> setLanguage(language === 'en' ? 'ar' : 'ar')
> setDirection(direction === "left" ? "right" : "right")
> }
> else if(direction === "right"){
> setAnimateLeft(animateLeft === true)
> }
>
> }
>
> const handleEnglishDirection = () => {
> if(direction === "left"){
> setAnimateLeft(animateLeft === true)
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> else if(direction === "right"){
> setAnimateLeft(animateLeft === false)
> setDirection( "left" )
> setLanguage(language === 'ar' ? 'en' : 'en')
> }
> setAnimate(animate === false)
> }
>
> useEffect(() => {
> localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(text));
> [text]);
>
> return (
>
> begin::Body */}
>
> begin::Form */}
>
> begin::Wrapper */}
> <div className={`w-lg-500px p-10' box ${animate ? 'animateRight' : animateLeft ? 'animateLeft' : ""}` }  style={{ direction: directionMap[direction], }}  >
>
> {/*
>
> ## {text.header}
>
> */}
> {/*
>
> {text.content}
>
> */}
>
>
> English
>
> {/* 
> Arabic
>  */}
> Arabic
>
>
> end::Wrapper */}
>
> end::Form */}
>
> begin::Footer */}
>
> begin::Links */}
> {/* 
>
> Terms
>
> ```
>         <a href='#' className='px-5' target='_blank'>
> ```
>
> Plans
>
> ```
>         <a href='#' className='px-5' target='_blank'>
> ```
>
> Contact Us
>
>  */}
> end::Links */}
>
> end::Footer */}
>
> end::Body */}
>
> begin::Aside */}
> <div
> className='d-flex flex-lg-row-fluid w-lg-50 bgi-size-cover bgi-position-center order-1 order-lg-2'
> style={{backgroundImage: `url(${toAbsoluteUrl('/media/misc/auth-bg.png')})`}}
> >
> begin::Content */}
>
> begin::Logo */}
>
> <img alt='Logo' src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/logos/custom-1.png')} className='h-75px' />
>
> end::Logo */}
>
> begin::Image */}
> <img
> className='mx-auto w-275px w-md-50 w-xl-500px mb-10 mb-lg-20'
> src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/misc/auth-screens.png')}
> alt=''
> />
> end::Image */}
>
> begin::Title */}
>
> Fast, Efficient and Productive
>
> end::Title */}
>
> begin::Text */}
>
> In this kind of post,{' '}
>
> the blogger
>
> introduces a person they’ve interviewed 
>  and provides some background information
> about
>
> the interviewee
>
> and their 
>  work following this is a transcript of the interview.
>
> end::Text */}
>
> end::Content */}
>
> end::Aside */}
>
> )
> }
>
> export {AuthLayout}
>
> .box {
> transform: rotateY(0deg);
> transition: transform 7s;
> }
>
> .animateRight {
> transform: rotateY(360deg) !important;
> }
>
> .animateLeft {
> transform: rotateY(-360deg) !important;
> }
>
> ```
> type here
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to flip the login component when i will click on a button .The content should be flipped along with direction like ltr to rtl but the background like image must be its own place .how can i achieve it?